# In a group by, is there a way to tell SQL no aggregate function should be needed for a specific column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have recently started working with T-SQL and have come across a difficulty with the group by functionality.

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns : Column_1, Column_2 and Column_3. I know that for a given value of Column_1, Column_2 will always have a given value. Column_3 on the other hand is independent from Column_1.

So the table could look like this :

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3 
1           42          57 
1           42          35 
2           3           5
2           3           6 
5           78          45
```

I want to do a group by on Column_1 in order to aggregate Column_3 (let's say with a sum()). However, as I am doing a group by, I have to group by or aggregate Column_2 even though I know it isn't necessary.

So my SQL request would be:

```
select Column_1, Column_2, sum(Column_3) 
from Table 
group by Column_1, Column_2
```

or

```
select Column_1, max(Column_2), sum(Column_3) 
from Table 
group by Column_1
(using max as a workaround to avoid grouping by Column_2)
```

My question is: Is there any way to tell SQL that no aggregate function should be needed for Column_2 and have SQL check that assumption is correct?

I would consider this an optimal option as it enables me to be sure my assumption is correct. When using the two previous requests, I am never 100% sure that is the case (except if I check it in another way before the request) and could make a mistake difficult to identify (especially when using the max workaround).

Ideally, I would like to be able to write something like :

```
select Column_1, no_agg_necessary(Column_2), sum(Column_3) 
from Table 
group by Column_1
```

that would come up with a warning if Column_2 values are not identical when grouped by a given Column_1 value.

I was thinking something like this to select Column_2 could answer my need :

```
case when count(distinct Column_2) = 1 then max(Column_2) else raiseerror() end as Column_2
```

But it doesn't seem possible to use a raiseerror() in such a context and adding the distinct slows down the request.

Do you know of any SQL functionality that would answer my need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported, in SQL Server or any other database.  Functional dependencies are supported in some database, but they look at the definition of the tables to see if the value has to be related (i.e. `column1` is `unique`).  They do not check if the data has a unique value in other circumstances.

SQL in general -- and SQL Server in particular -- is not particular adept at generating errors in `SELECT` statements.  It is possible using a `CASE` expressions.  In a non-aggregation query, SQL Server guarantees the order of evaluation, going so far as to not evaluate errors during the compilation phase.

So, you *could* write what you want as:

```
select x,
       (case when min(y) = max(y)
             then min(y) else convert(int, 'Bad column value')
        end)
from (values (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)) v(x, y)
group by x;
```

I don't really recommend approaching queries in this way.  You should validate your data as a separate step, so you are not surprised by the results that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is lacking a "problem"

How would you handle the query if I add the row

1 - 41 - 19

You now have multiple values for that column. How would desire the result?

41? 42? "invalid"?

So in order to keep the data correct you would need to slice it into 2 result records most likely, which you would achieve by adding it to the group clause.

If you don't care about the data that much you can use a dummy function like min() or max() or if you are going to be fancy you can inject a value "invalid" if Min() <> Max()

Comment: In the case of the row you added, I would have liked the result to return an error, as in my understanding the table should not be built in a way that this row could be present. So I would have liked to make my query on that assumption and get an error if my assumption is false (or if the table contains an error, or if the table evolves in time for some reason or another).

Comment: Ok, the error makes it harder... You need a real exception or will a tag like "ERR" be ok ? If the tag is ok, you can use IF to compare min(field) and max(field) - if they deviate from each other output err if not just use min or max...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will be going with Gordon's suggestion that data should be validated in a separate step prior to the desired querie. As you both pointed out, it is possible to get an error tag by comparing min and max, which I hadn't thought of. However, this means having to check for the presence of the tag afterwards, so I might as well validate the data beforehand as I'll have to validate in both cases !

Comment: If you say "cant happen" you can consider slapping a unique index onto the table that will enforce it. That way wrong data cant be entered and you don't need to check during query time